# Не работает window.onload в javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta="UTF-8">
    <title>Game</title>
    <script src ="main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="gameName">Game</div>
    <canvas id="map"></canvas>

</body>
</html>

window.onload = init();
var map;
var ctxMap;
var gameWidth = 800;
var gameHeight = 500;

function init()
{

    map = document.getElementById("map");

    ctxMap = map.getContext("2d");

}
```

Ошибка:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'getContext' of null

Comment: @wewewe777, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло